# Asymptotic Expansion for an Integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, asymptotics, power-series

So I have

$$\psi(x)=\int_{2\lambda}^x \frac{(e\lambda)^{z}}{z^{z+1/2}} dz$$

I'm trying to find the asymptotic expansion of $\psi(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ for as many orders as possible. How would I go about doing this?

Note: $\lambda>0$

Comment: By $e \lambda$, can you confirm that you mean $e$ (the number such that $ln(e)=1$) $times \lambda$ ?

Comment: By $e\lambda$, I mean $e*\lambda$ (multiplying two numbers).

Comment: it turns out that the integral is heavly dominated by the left endpoint....

Comment: Ok, well the left endpoint varies on $\lambda$, but I'm wondering how you got that result. Unless we have $\lambda \to 0$, I don't see why the impact of the left tail would have an impact on its asymptotics. So I guess we'd have to branch it into two different zones:
1. $\lambda$ in the neighborhood of 0
2. $\lambda>z_0>0$